# Методика работы с проектом в workspace Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse

Для работы с другими IDE использую следующую методику:

1. Проект со всеми настройками хранится в папке.
2. Содержимое под версионным контролем Git.
3. На флешке --bare (пустой) репазиторий куда я сидываю изменения.
4. И соответственно в любом месте имею полную копию проекта.

В Eclipse такая методика не работает, так как часть настроек отображения файлов (редакторы swing, xml …) хранятся в workspace, т.е. для нормальной работы надо или носить 2 репазитория (репазиторий с проектом, репазиторий с настройками из workspace) или устанавливать все настройки IDE в ручную
(а это зачастую проблематично).
Подскажите оптимальную методику работы?

Comment: А кто мешает таскать на флэшке workspace, и при старте eclipse на другой машине указывать ему это самый workspace? Правда, тут можно нарваться на отсутствующие на другой машине плагины, несоответствие версий, и т.д. Поэтому, IMHO, проще таскать на флэшке сам Eclipse полностью, с workspace и проектами. не знаю как под виндами, но под линуксом никаких проблем с этим нет.

Comment: я так и делаю но хотелось бы иметь резервную копию, (именно рабочую) а то влешка сломалась и все потерялось. А сам workspce под контроль git брать проблемно надо будет с субмодулями разбиратся, может есть какое простое решение?

Comment: Например вы можете использовать maven и им при необходимости восстанавливать воркспейс.

Comment: А весь workspace и не надо, достаточно каталог `.metadata` внутри него. Во всяком случае в линуксе, в виндах не знаю как организовано. Ну и/или да, есть плагины для сохранения конфигураций.

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос как в mavin проекте указать зависимости на файлы генерируемые средой в папке .metadata автоматом он их не ставит, что в ручную их искать?

Comment: Вообще если есть гарантия, что на разных машинах работа с данным workspace идёт в разное время, то можно и так (при условии, что `.metadata` в гите):  http://ideone.com/U5vM5g

Comment: Наверно не стоит пытаться копировать workspace все-таки это настройки для конкретной машины.
На надо в каждой рабочей IDE устанавливать настройки самостоятельно
Например для установки редактора визуального редактора для работы с UI 
Click ПКМ в текстовом редакторе Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor